# How do I get more accurate geotags with the GPS logging feature of the Panasonic Image App on iOS?

Tags: iphone, geotagging, panasonic, gps

I tried out the GPS logging and geotagging features of the [Panasonic Image App](https://itunes.apple.com/app/panasonic-image-app/id590212732) today. I’ve managed to transfer the log from my iPhone to the camera and to apply it to the pictures. But it seems the location log was only updated a handful of times, all pictures appear as shot on one of just four locations. I’ve left the app’s setting of how often to update to the default of every 5 seconds, and I’ve checked that in the iOS Settings the app’s access to location services is set to “always” (meaning the app should have access even when running in the background). Is there anything else I need to do to get a more accurate log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having gone through the section on the app in my camera’s manual again, I noticed it says:

> (When using “Image App” for iOS)
>   If you press the Home or On/Off button on the smartphone while location information is being recorded, the recording will stop.

I take it to mean the app only works as long as it is the front app and the device is not locked, which is rather restrictive. I gave the following a try: the app shows a count of the number of times it has logged the location, so I started the log, locked my iPhone and left it like that for 10 minutes then checked the app again. The count had only increased by about 40, indicating the app stopped logging after around 3 minutes.

I assume this has to do with the limitations iOS imposes on apps, though on the other hand I haven’t seen a similar caveat mentioned in reviews for apps like [GeoTagr](https://itunes.apple.com/app/id294194869) and [Geotag Photos Pro](https://itunes.apple.com/app/id1008694552), so I will give one of those a try instead.